# why does ((a(-b)?)(?!Z)) match the a in "a-bZ"?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to write a regular Expression that matches

```
a
a-b
```

but only if these sequences are not followed by Z

```
((a(-b)?)(?!Z))

a       matches a       ok
a-b     matches a-b     ok
aZ      empty           ok
a-bZ    matches a       NOT OK
```

Why does "a-bZ" match the first a although there is a group around (a(-b)?)  ?
How can I correct it?

Need this in javascript RegExp, which should not matter however. Tried it in http://regexpal.com/

Comment: The `(a(-b)?)` matches as `a` since the b is optional, and then it is followed by `-` which is _not_ a Z so the negative lookahead isn't matched. It makes perfect sense.

Comment: you are right, i mixed lookahead with consuming, thx.

Comment: ?> is not suported in js

Comment: How about [/(a(?!(-b)?Z)(-b)?))/](http://regex101.com/r/dK1bJ3/1) then?

Comment: thx @raina77ow, yes, that works, the drawback is that my terms for a and b are pretty long, so repeating b hurts a bit. But looks like there is no way out. Thx also to point to regex101, really cool.

Comment: Yes, the repetition is the drawback; this case is exactly what atomics are for. Let's say the JS regex flavor isn't among the bright ones.

Comment: @city How about simply adding anchors in your regex http://regex101.com/r/dK1bJ3/2 ?

Comment: anchors are not possible, the question here reduces the problem a lot. the key insight was that i mixed lookahead with consuming. so thx to Benjamin and all who contributed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a-bZ` is matched because `(-b)?` is ignored and `(?!Z)` matches the `-` symbol.

Because `(-b)` is optional, every string of the form `((a)(?!Z))` also gets matched.
You could match `(a(?!Z))|(a-b(?!Z))`

However, this will match `a-bZ` (because a is followed by a non-Z character).

If you want to find all instances of the strings where, for example, `a-c` doesn't get matched (even though `-` is a non-Z character), you could do this:

```
(a(?![-Z]))|(a-b(?!Z))
```

Comment: ?! doesn't consume characters from the match, which I think is worth mentioning too

Answer (score 2):

You could use *atomic grouping* to make your regex work. Unfortunately, the JavaScript regex engine does not support this feature.

But there is a trick to mimic its effect using a look-ahead and a back-reference ([explained here](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-atomic-groups)):

```
(?=(pattern to make atomic))\1
```

so with your `a-b` or just `a` situation, this would become:

```
(?=(a-b|a))\1(?!Z)
```

Note that the longer sub-pattern `a-b` needs to be mentioned first in the group, otherwise it does not work.

The key mechanism is that the look-ahead finds the ealiest, longest-possible sub-match, while the back-reference prevents any backtracking in the engine and moves the position in the string, so the following test `(?!Z)` can be executed.

Comment: Actually, this works without any repetition in the pattern - `/(?=(a(-b)?))\1(?!Z)/` ([demo](http://regex101.com/r/wL9uQ9/1)), for the same reason - the longest pattern in look-ahead is tried first. How this answer isn't accepted by the OP is the real puzzle for me. )

Comment: It came too late. Speaking from my experience: regex threads on SO usually die at the first workable answer, seldom the OP gives any thought or credit to the presented alternatives.

Comment: @raina77ow: The longest pattern is tried first due to the greediness of the `?`, like how the ordering of `a-b|a` implies the order of trial. You will understand my point when you make it lazy: `/(?=(a(-b)??))\1(?!Z)/`

Answer (score 1):

If you specify the start and end anchors, the above regex `((a(-b)?)(?!Z))` wouldn't match the string `a-bZ`, see the demo [here](http://regex101.com/r/kE0wF3/1). Because the anchors are not specified and the `(-b)` is made optional, the regex engine try to match `a-b` anywhere  at first and then discards the match on seeing the following  `Z` letter. Now the regex engine backtracks because of the optional `-b` to get a match. Now it's on `a`,  the letter `a` is not immediately followed by `Z`, so the engine now matches the letter `a`